# You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in your environment - How to set the default value of NODE_ENV in windows

Tags: node.js, next.js, environment-variables, next.js13, nodeenv

I changed the value of `NODE_ENV` to production using the command:

```
setx NODE_ENV production
```

Now in my nextjs project, anytime I run `npm run dev` or `build`, I get the error: **You are using a non-standard "NODE_ENV" value in you environment.**

[image: node_env error in nextjs project]

After doing some research, I found out this property is automatically provided by Nextjs and the default value is `NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV` (I may be wrong about this).

I've tried to change the value back to the default: using `setx NODE_ENV NEXT_PUBLIC_APP_ENV` which works. Here's the result of running `node` followed by `process.env` in my terminal to confirm the change.

[image]

The problem is I still get the error every time I run npm run build or dev and in any nextjs project on my PC. I'm I missing something or is there another place this property is being added? Please help.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was stored in my computer's environment variable. If you're on windows 7/10/11, here's the solution to fix this.

Hold down `Win + R` to open the run box and enter `sysdm.cpl` to open your system properties.

Next, navigate to the advanced tab and click `Environment variables` at the bottom.

[image]

You should see a list of all the `env` variables stored on your PC. Among the list should be the variable for `NODE_ENV`. Simply delete it and click okay to set it to default.

> Note: You may need to restart your terminal to see the changes.

[image]